# How to stream a local file to the Chromecast?

Tags: ios, google-cast

Is it possible to stream a local file from an iOS app bundle to the Chromecast ?

```
(IBAction)sendThisFileToChromeCast{
    NSString *fp = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"bunny" ofType:@"m4v"];
    GCKMediaInformation *mediaInformation = [
        [GCKMediaInformation alloc] initWithContentID:fp
        streamType:GCKMediaStreamTypeNone
        contentType:@"video/mp4"
        metadata:nil
        streamDuration:596.46
        customData:nil
        ];
    [self.mediaControlChannel loadMedia:mediaInformation autoplay:YES playPosition:0.0]; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write a small web server to serve the local file and send the url of the media that your app is serving to your Cast device and then your receiver app should be able to get the media and play it.

Comment: How does one go about writing this web server? Could you provide a little more information, or some resources to help? Coming from a purely Android/Java background here..

Comment: Yes would you go about writting one of these Web servers?

Comment: Have you done any google search for that? If you do, you will get some hits and you can choose one that you like.

Comment: Yes I have done some searches and nothing is really turning up. Maybe I'm searching in the wrong place. Maybe you can post a link to some help on the topic or point me in the right direction. Any help will be really helpful. Thanks

Comment: I don't use iOS but a quick search showed many hits, like this one: https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaHTTPServer